# Show the $\mathbb{C} S_3$-module of dimension 2 has $S(V \otimes V)$ is not irreducible

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, tensor-products

Consider the $\mathbb{C} S_3$-module of dimension 2, call it $V$.

I want to concretely show that $S(V \otimes V)$ is not irreducible.

I found a representation for $S_3$ over $\mathbb{C}$ of degree 2, but I don't know where to go from there.

I'm not sure what the tensor product looks like. Do I just square all the matrices? Then pick out the eigenvectors or something? A bit lost. Or very lost.

Comment: Is $S(W)$ the symmetric algebra generated by $W$? Or is it supposed to be the symmetric tensor product $S^2(V)$?

Answer (score 3):

If $S(V\otimes V)$ is meant to represent the symmetric tensor product of two copies of $V$, then $\dim S^2 V= 3$, which is not the dimension of any of the three finite dimensional irreps of $S_3$. If $S(V\otimes V)$ instead represents the direct sum $\oplus S^k(V\otimes V)$, then each graded piece is an invariant subspace, so it is reducible.